# Does it make sense to wrap the SQL Server Serilog sink inside Async?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, serilog

I am trying to minimize the performance impact of writing logs to SQL Server from a .NET Core application.

In the past I've wrapped a Serilog `File` sink inside of an `Async` sink - and that greatly helped performance.

The [SQL Server sink documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver) states that it batches log entries periodically and/or when `batchPostingLimit` has been reached. What I can't find is any information on what happens when it does decide to issue an `INSERT` command.

Does it happen asynchronously relative to the code that called `Logger.Log(...)` or not? If not, does it make sense to wrap the SQL Server Serilog sink inside Async?

Comment: SQL Server Profiler can tell you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017  Also probably Visual Studio IntelliTrace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/intellitrace-features?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SQL Server sink [derives from `PeriodicBatchingSink`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/Sinks/MSSqlServer/MSSqlServerSink.cs#L31), which executes all batched operations asynchronously.

So no, *Serilog.Sinks.Async* won't improve the performance of the SQL Server sink in its current form.